# github gitignore adds folder previously NOT on gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

i have mistankenly added a folder on a github project that I don't want to be there anymore. I want/need it only in my local project.

so i've updated my .gitignore file adding the directory name, i've committed and pushed the changes but the folder is still on github.

i've another contributor to the project. what could it be? maybe he should update his gitignore too and commit something for this to be effective?

I did exactly the same thing on this same project with another mistankenly added file and it worked, the only difference is that now I have an extra contributor to the project.

Comment: Have you tried removing the folder with `git rm`?

Comment: You need to delete the folder as well, not only ignore it.

Comment: Use `git rm --cached <file>` to remove the file from the repo but keep it on your machine. This will however keep the file in the history so if it has sensitive info in it someone will still be able to find it by looking back at the commit history. You will also need to `add/commit/push` to see the change son github.

Comment: I don't care about the reputation points, but I strongly urge you to understand that `filter-branch` is not a tool that should be used without a very good reason. If you use it regularly, especially without fully understanding what it does, it *will eventually bite you*. You say you're working with a contributor, so I think it will bite you sooner rather than later. **The repository on GitHub and your collaborator's copy no longer share the commits they once did.** Wait until that person tries to push to the repository and you'll find what a mess `filter-branch` has gotten you into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was that *git always track the files that git knows* so if you have tracked a file previously to add it to the `.gitignore`, git is not going to take into account that change. Be careful the next time ;)

There are two different contexts where you have tracked files that you don't want to track anymore.

1. Files or directories that you don't really want to share in your repository, so you need to remove them from the entire repository history like password (for security reasons), configuration files, binaries, big resources files, etc.
2. Files or directories that you haven't include in your .gitignore file, that you don't want to track but that you don't mind to maintain in your repository history

***Remove permanently***

If you are in the first situation, you have to use `filter-branch --tree-filter` and pass the command you want to exec.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'YOUR COMMAND' HEAD
```

**This command will remove permanently the files or directories you indicate from the whole repository history, and force other collaborators to perform a `git pull -f`to synchronize the repo with the new remote state**, so be careful because you can't undo that!

For example if you have tracked a file named `Keys.plist` the traditional command to remove it would be `rm Keys.plist`. In case you want tu ensure that this runs, I recommend you to add `-f` parameter to force the remove

Example:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f Keys.plist' HEAD
```

In your case you want to remove a directory so I suppose you need to add -R to the rm command as follows:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f -R YourDirectory' HEAD
```

So now, you need to push your branch to your remote repository with

```
git push origin YourBranch -f
```

Don't forget it to include `-f` to force the update in the remote repository.

***Only not track those files in the future***

This is more simple, you are in the second context and you don't mind that your files go on appearing in your repository history.

So in that case, you have to use `git rm --cached -r YourDirectory`

Don't forget to include this time your dinrectories or files that you don't want to track in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: i have to remove the folder called bower_components. so i typed git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f -R bower_components' HEAD but it's still on github :/

Comment: Make a push with -f also, sorry I forgot it to tell you that in my answer. `git push origin YourBranch -f`

Comment: i keep forgetting to 'push' :)

Comment: i don't know why but now the folder disappeared from my local project as well

Comment: This command `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f -R bower_components' HEAD` only deletes the file from your git, did you execute `rm -f -R bower_components` without git in front of the command?

Comment: This is a very poor answer. `git filter-branch` is only appropriate in a small number of cases. It rewrites every commit, causing your commit hashes to change. This has serious implications, particularly with shared repositories, and should never be recommended without carefully explaining them. It should never be the first tool you reach for. Having to force push (`git push -f`) is a warning that you're doing something dangerous. In this case a simple `git rm --cached -r YourDirectory`, then `commit` and `push`, would have sufficed, and would have been much more appropriate.

Comment: Only use `git rm --cached -r YourDirectory` is very dangerous if you have tracked files that you really don't want to share. My answer solves this, yours not because mine delete those files from repository history forever. Imagine you have share in a public repository your API keys or database password by mistake.

Comment: @EnriMR, nowhere in the question does the OP state that the file is sensitive and should therefore be purged from the history. "i have mistankenly added a folder on a github project that I don't want to be there anymore". This suggests using a simple `rm --cached`. To say that this is "very dangerous" while recommending the *actually* dangerous `filter-branch` *without any warning whatsoever* is irresponsible. "Imagine you have share in a public repository your API keys or database password by mistake." Then you're missing the most important step: to invalidate those keys.

Comment: @EnriMR, in fact, in the first comment on your answer the OP states "i have to remove the folder called bower_components". This is simply [the install location for Bower](http://bower.io/#install-packages). It is exceedingly unlikely that it contains any sensitive keys or passwords, making `rm --cached` the significantly better choice.

Comment: @EnriMR, and the OP states in the question that they are working with a collaborator. You haven't suggested any way for the two developers to get back in sync after using `filter-branch`, which (depending on the history) could be a huge task. You haven't even warned them about this. I stand by my assertion that `filter-branch` is the wrong tool to use in this case.

Comment: I have improved my answer, thanks @Chris . But I don't understand your behavior

Comment: @EnriMR, my behaviour is motivated by the fact that your original answer *directly leads the OP to major problems*. Any recommendation to use `filter-branch`, `push -f`, or similar "rewrite history" tools should be accompanied with a strong warning. This is especially true when working with a collaborator, like here. `rm --cached` is simply a better option in this case. It's safer, easier, and it encourages the use of a "regular" Git command instead of a "nuclear" one. Your new answer is better, but you still don't mention invalidating keys or collaboration problems caused by changed hashes.

Comment: Thanks for the further update, @EnriMR. I have removed my downvote, and upvoted your new answer. Overuse of `filter-branch` is a pet peeve of mine for (I think) good reasons.